# Approach for testing XXE injection

Tags: web-application, injection, xml, xxe

I have been discussing xxe injection in my web application,My web application allows expansion of user-supplied XML entities

What i did:

Intercepted traffic using Burp.

Changed the request with `Accept: text/xml`

Inject the XML in cookie and check the response.

AS a result of XML expansion ,the response included with xml whatever i injected

Other things which i tried:

I tried with [xxeinjector](https://github.com/enjoiz/XXEinjector) in terminal and got the response from server, which will help me to confirm there is a XML expansion

In order to make proof of concept how can I illustrate the XXE attack on my web application?

Is the above behavior correct? Is my approach towards XXE injection right?

If it's wrong, please kindly guide me how to perform XEE checks.

Answer (score 1):

Some good resources related to XXE:

- https://portswigger.net/web-security/xxe
- https://github.com/swisskyrepo/PayloadsAllTheThings/tree/master/XXE%20Injection
- https://book.hacktricks.xyz/pentesting-web/xxe-xee-xml-external-entity